# Transition to Neutron Star

Tags: cosmology, gravity, matter

If we're asked to believe that the explosive aspect of a supernova results from a rebound of residual free falling matter off of the stellar core, shouldn't we also be asked to believe that transition to Neutron Star occurred first and the edge formed, faster than the residual free falling matter falls, faster than gravity alone would accomplish?

Comment: *faster than gravity alone would accomplish* There is no additional attractive force, at least not in mainstream physics.

Comment: *If we're asked to believe…* Physics does not ask anyone to “believe” anything. It constructs models to try to accurately describe the world. They either work well or they don’t, when compared with observations. No attractive force other than gravity is required to explain what we have observed.

Comment: Do you understand that gravitational acceleration varies at different distances from the center?

Comment: Yes the closer you get the greater the acceleration, but wouldn't that only be until terminal velocity is reached?

Comment: Thank you ghoster, I won't ask any more questions, I've been sufficiently answered a number of times, I just wasn't sure if collapse speeds have been measured or proven or if it's a given that collapse speeds can never be greater than free fall speeds because of the way gravity works. But this is my last question and thank you for all your responses.

Comment: *I won't ask any more questions.* There is no reason to stop asking questions. If you think any of my comments are out of line, you should flag them.

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I don’t see how collapse speeds could be faster than freefall speeds since gravity is the only attractive force at work. Let’s see if an expert will answer.

Comment: Ghoster you're fine and all's good, I'm just at the end of wondering and I'm at a point where I can believe what I believe, faster collapse speed would just be icing on the cake anyway.

Comment: What's at work here is transition from one of 3 primary states of matter, regular matter, into the second primary state of matter, neutron star. Likewise when black holes form, transition from neutron star to the 3rd state of matter, primordial matter squeezed in the center of a black hole. These are transitions of matter from one state to the next, not gravity crushers. So they shouldn't be defined by how gravity works, they should be defined by how transitions between states of matter work. Just try defining the speed of core transition without using the gravitational acceleration factor.

Comment: We've been given great, great clues to how the universe works with supernovas and their aftermath being observable, maybe even measurable, let's not blow it explaining it away in any terms other than what is the essence of a transition of matter from one state to the next. Forget gravity, it can lead to unreasonable assumptions.

Comment: So for now let's think about if there's a flaw in competing theories, 1 that supernovas are rebounding of free falling matter against the edge of the core, and 2 that the core forms only as fast as free falling matter. Isn't there a logical fallacy there? What edge? What rebound? A pancaking of edges like the World Trade Center? Rebounds off of every pancaking edge?

Comment: If you want to see a gravity crusher, look at the involuntary transition of  regular matter directly to primordial matter in spaghettification and accretion discs in quasars and active galactic nuclei, now that's a gravity crusher. But not so-called stellar collapses, those are instantaneous transitions of matter from one primary state to the next in response to the reaching of cosmic mass limits (net mass).